# Can not follow derivation of $WZ(0, 0)$ amplitude in paper

Tags: polarization, bosons, large-hadron-collider, electroweak, helicity

i am re-reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9403248) paper and trying to follow the derivation of equation (21) from equation (15).

Maybe someone can tell me where i am going wrong.

So the original equation 15 is:

$$M(0,0) = F\frac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt{2r_Wr_Z}}[(A)X + 2 \beta\rho Y]$$

We are going into the limit $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty}$
This makes $r_W, r_Z$ go to zero and thus $\beta,\alpha,\rho,\beta_W,\beta_Z$ to one. With that the whole $A$ term should go to zero and the whole $X$ term can be ignored.

Thus we are left with

$$M(0,0)=F\frac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt{2r_Wr_Z}}\times2Y$$

Comparing this to our target we have

$$2F\frac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt{2r_Wr_Z}}Y \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{F}{2}\sin\theta \frac{M_Z}{M_W}(g_2-g_1)$$

Cutting this down a bit already we get

$$\frac{s}{M_WM_Z}Y \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{2}\frac{M_Z}{M_W}(g_1-g_2)$$

Now i will just look again at the left side and expand the $Y$
\begin{align}
\frac{s}{M_WM_Z}Y &= \frac{s}{M_WM_Z}g_1\frac{M_Z^2s}{2us(1-\frac{M_W^2}{s})}\\
&= \frac{s}{M_WM_Z}g_1\frac{M_Z^2s}{-s^2(1+\cos\theta)(1-\frac{M_W^2}{s})}
\end{align}

where i used $u = -\frac{s}{2}(\alpha + \beta\cos\theta)$ from (7).
Now we cancel things and take the limit $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty}$ again and get

$$\frac{-1}{M_W}g_1\frac{M_Z}{(1+\cos\theta)} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{2}\frac{M_Z}{M_W}(g_1-g_2)$$

or

$$\frac{-g_1}{(1+\cos\theta)} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{2}(g_1-g_2)$$

Which does not hold for arbitrary values of $g_1,g_2,\theta$.

(Afterwards i have 2 more question with how this paper related to another, specifically https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08688 and equations (13))

Comment: thanks for spotting that. as you said, that was just a mistake in the typing. The the derivation used it correctly. I have now also added the other two beta to the list of variables that go to 1.

Comment: As a sanity check, convince yourself you appreciate the general formulas for $f_1= e^-$, when they simplify dramatically. Make sure they all make sense on both sides of you logic barrier. In fact, it's good mental hygiene to review the  ref [3] paper of Goebel et al ***first***.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just that the $X$ term can not be ignored. The $Y$ term scales as $1/s$. And the $A$ term does so as well while the $X$ itself scales as $s^0$. Thus it can not be ignored.

Taking it into consideration yields:

$$\frac{M_Z^2}{s}(-1+\cos\theta)X$$ for $A\times X$

With that ones get
\begin{align}
g_2-g_1 &\stackrel{?}{=} (-1+\cos\theta)X - 2\frac{g_1}{1+\cos\theta}\\
&=(1-\cos\theta)(\frac{g_1}{1+\cos\theta}+\frac{g_2}{1-\cos\theta}) - 2\frac{g_1}{1+\cos\theta}\\
&=g_2 + \frac{g_1(1-\cos\theta)}{1+\cos\theta}-2\frac{g_1}{1+\cos\theta}\\
&=g_2 + \frac{g_1-\cos\theta g_1 - 2g_1}{1+\cos\theta}\\
&= g_2 + \frac{-g_1 - g_1\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}\\
&= g_2 + \frac{g_1(-1-\cos\theta)}{1+\cos\theta}\\
&= g_2 + \frac{-g_1(1+\cos\theta)}{1+\cos\theta}\\
&\stackrel{!}{=} g_2 - g_1
\end{align}