# Derivation of hypercharge neglecting squared amplitude for WZ helicities in paper

Tags: polarization, bosons, large-hadron-collider, electroweak, helicity

I am trying to get from equations (20) and (21) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9403248) to equations (13) in [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08688).

I will start with my attempt at deriving this for the LL case.
(With $F$ from equation (4), $g_2-g_1$ from (9)

\begin{align}
\frac{g^4}{16}\sin^2\theta &\stackrel{?}{=} \left|\frac{F}{2}\sin\theta\frac{M_Z}{M_W}(g_2-g_1)\right|^2 \\
&= \frac{e^4}{4\times2\sin^2\theta_W}\sin^2\theta\frac{M^2_Z}{M^2_W}\cot^2\theta_W\\
&= \frac{1}{8}\frac{e^4}{\sin^2\theta_W}\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta_W}\frac{\cos^2\theta_W}{\sin^2\theta_W}\sin^2\theta\\
&= \frac{1}{8} \frac{e^4}{\sin^4\theta_W}\sin^2\theta\\
&= \frac{g^4}{8}\sin^2\theta\\
&= 2 \frac{g^4}{16}\sin^2\theta
\end{align}

So i do get the general formula but i am off by a factor of 2.

Now to the TT case

\begin{align}
\frac{g^4}{32}(\frac{s}{t}-\frac{s}{u})^2\sin^2\theta(1+\cos^2\theta) &\stackrel{?}{=} \sum_{\lambda_W = \pm 1}\left|\frac{F}{\sin\theta}(\lambda_W-\cos\theta)\left[(g_1-g_2)\cos\theta-(g_1+g_2)\right]\right|^2\\
\end{align}

Here, we need the assumption that $Q^f = T^f_3$ as per ("neglecting the contribution
from the hypercharge"). This means that $g_1+g_2=0$ And i also made the assumption that we have to sum of $\lambda_W$ as we are not separating the (-,+) and (+,-) states. Lets begin with modifying the target a bit.

\begin{align}
(\frac{s}{t}-\frac{s}{u})^2 &= (\frac{-2}{1-\cos\theta}-\frac{-2}{1+\cos\theta})^2 \\
&=  (\frac{2}{1+\cos\theta}-\frac{2}{1-\cos\theta})^2\\
&= (\frac{2(1-\cos\theta)-2(1+\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta})^2\\
&= (\frac{-4\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta})^2\\
&= \frac{16\cos^2\theta}{\sin^4\theta}
\end{align}

So now we have

\begin{align}
\frac{g^4}{2}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}(1+\cos^2\theta) &\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{\lambda_W = \pm 1}\left|\frac{F}{\sin\theta}(\lambda_W-\cos\theta)\left[(g_1-g_2)\cos\theta-(g_1+g_2)\right]\right|^2\\
&= \frac{F^2}{\sin^2\theta}\cot^2\theta_W\cos^2\theta \times \sum_{\lambda_W = \pm 1} (\lambda_W-\cos\theta)^2\\
&= \frac{e^4}{2\sin^2\theta_W}\frac{\cos^2\theta_W}{\sin^2\theta_W}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\times \sum_{\lambda_W = \pm 1} (\lambda_W-\cos\theta)^2\\
&= \frac{g^4}{2}\cos\theta_W \frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta} \times 2(1+\cos^2\theta)\\
&= 2\cos\theta_W \frac{g^4}{2}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}(1+\cos^2\theta)
\end{align}

Which again, seems close but is off by a factor $2\cos\theta_W$. And with assuming that $g^\prime=0$ then $\cos\theta_W=1$. So it is again a factor two compared to what i want. Does anyone know where that comes from?

This is a follow up question to [Can not follow derivation of $WZ(0, 0)$ amplitude in paper](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/790558/can-not-follow-derivation-of-wz0-0-amplitude-in-paper/790665#790665)